# How to change the circle radius when I click on them (with three.js)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the following JavaScript code, taken from an example, which draws some circles, and when you click on one of them, it changes color. But I also want to change the radius/size of a circle when you click on that circle (and leave the other circles unchanged). The [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/CircleGeometry) does not help at all, and I have tried several variations in the code like

```
intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.parameters.radius = 50;
intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.radius = 50;
intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.setRadius(50);
```

Anyway, here is the complete code:

```
var container, camera, scene, geometry, mesh, renderer, controls, particles, colors;
var objects = [];

// DOM element...
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

// Camera...
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 75);

// Scene...
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);

// Renderer...
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    clearAlpha: 1
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);         

// Scatter plot...
scatterPlot = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(scatterPlot);

// Make grid...
xzColor = 'black';
xyColor = 'black';
yzColor = 'black';



// Plot some random points...
circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5);

colors = [];
var max = 50;
var min = -50;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          

    var object = new THREE.Mesh( circle, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 } ) );
    object.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    object.position.z = 0;                  

    scene.add( object );
    objects.push( object );

}

animate();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
        intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.setRadius(50);
        var particle = new THREE.Sprite( particleMaterial );
        particle.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );
        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 16;
        scene.add( particle );
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can solve this? And where can I find the proper documentation?

Addendum:

- I have used the following line of code:

  intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.scale(1.1,1.1,1.1);

In the code, and now the circles change their size. But ALL of them! I click on one circle, and every circle changes size. Does not make sense to me...

Comment: try this `var object = new THREE.Mesh( circle.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 } ) );`

Comment: Ah much better! And right, it was the same object. Thanks..

Comment: TheJim01's answer is totally correct, so it's better rely on it, than on my comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't scale your `geometry`. You're using the same geometry reference for all of your circles, so scaling one scales them all.

Instead, scale your `Mesh`, which is a unique object in the scene (even if it references the same geometry as other meshes). Much like how you're setting `position` for each `Mesh`, you also have access to `scale`:

```
intersects[0].object.scale.set(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
```

That will scale the intersected `Mesh` object, and only that `Mesh`.

Cloning and creating a new `Mesh` is literally introducing a memory leak. The original `Mesh` won't go away until you remove it from the scene, and you keep making more and more `Geometry` objects as you `clone` the `circle`.